# javascript created template element not working

Tags: javascript, web-component

If I write a `template` node into the HTML by hand I can use it in my custom element just fine. If I create a `template` node and append it to the HTML using javascript when I try to use it, it's empty...

in the example below I make `template-a` the regular HTML way and make `template-b` to be the same shape using javascript. I define a very simple custom element that uses both templates. only `template-a` is visible.

```js
const sandbox = document.getElementById('sandbox')

const slot = document.createElement('slot')
slot.setAttribute('name', 'b')
slot.append('slot content goes here')
const em = document.createElement('em')
em.append(slot, '?')
const createdTemplate = document.createElement('template')
createdTemplate.setAttribute('id', 'template-b')
createdTemplate.append(em)
sandbox.append(createdTemplate)

customElements.define('test-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).append(
      ...['template-a','template-b']
      .map(id =>
        document.getElementById(id).content.cloneNode(true)
      )
    )
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="sandbox">
  <template id="template-a">
    <strong><slot name="a">slot content goes here</slot>!</strong>
  </template>
  <test-element>
    <span slot="a">some a slot content</span>
    <span slot="b">some b slot content</span>
  </test-element>
</div>
```

Comment: well that's embarrassing... I searched for a day before posting this and yep, there's an existing answer and it's exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes on your code:

#### this.shadowRoot

`this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })`

can become

`this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })`

this creates/sets `this.shadowRoot` for free

#### appendChild vs. append

Note that `.appendChild(el)` takes one element

and `.append()` takes an Array

Only difference is `appendChild()` **returns** a reference to the inserted element,
and `append()` returns nothing

So you can write:

```
em.appendChild(slot)
em.appendChild(document.createTextNode('?'))
```

as

```
em.append(slot, document.createTextNode('?'))
```

If you have Nodes in an Array:

```
let myElements = [slot, document.createTextNode('?')];
```

you can use the ES6 spread opperator:

```
em.append(...myElements)
```

This means you can write:

```
this.shadow.appendChild(document.getElementById('template-a').content.cloneNode(true))
this.shadow.appendChild(document.getElementById('template-b').content.cloneNode(true))
```

as:

```js
this.shadowRoot
 .append(
   ...['a','b']
      .map(templ => document.getElementById(`template-${templ}`).content.cloneNode(true))
  )
```

Comment: I've discovered (collided with) the shadowRoot thing but never bothered to see if it was a chrome thing or universal. I'll now consider it standard and idiomatic :)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas on more expressive node building I'll certainly use them in my projects. The example code is a little pedantic on purpose but I think your ideas wouldn't have hurt readability; if anything the opposite.

Comment: (edited my question and answer to include your suggestions)

Answer (score 0):

`template` nodes have a special `content` attribute which holds their children. (which I kind of knew but thought it was a little more magical than it is). If this line:

```
createdTemplate.append(em)
```

is changed to

```
createdTemplate.content.append(em)
```

then it all works

```js
const sandbox = document.getElementById('sandbox')

const slot = document.createElement('slot')
slot.setAttribute('name', 'b')
slot.append('slot content goes here')
const em = document.createElement('em')
em.append(slot, '?')
const createdTemplate = document.createElement('template')
createdTemplate.setAttribute('id', 'template-b')
createdTemplate.content.append(em)
sandbox.append(createdTemplate)

customElements.define('test-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).append(
      ...['template-a','template-b']
      .map(id =>
        document.getElementById(id).content.cloneNode(true)
      )
    )
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="sandbox">
  <template id="template-a">
    <strong><slot name="a">slot content goes here</slot>!</strong>
  </template>
  <test-element>
    <span slot="a">some a slot content</span>
    <span slot="b">some b slot content</span>
  </test-element>
</div>
```